# Optimize Inner Join SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search in my database the closest city from lat-long & range. To do that, I use this query :

```
SELECT ville_nom_reel FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free 
WHERE ville_latitude_deg BETWEEN 48.0462165495 AND 48.9471174505 
AND ville_longitude_deg BETWEEN -0.45045045045 AND 0.45045045045
```

*This query was executed in 0.0123 sec.*


Now I would like to Search in another database and retrieve 5 more fields from *ville_nom_reel* field from 1st Query. To do that, I used INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT villes_france_free.ville_nom_reel, villes_booking.full_name, villes_booking.number_of_hotels, villes_booking.deeplink  FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free 
INNER JOIN inspitravel.villes_booking ON villes_france_free.ville_nom_reel = villes_booking.full_name 
WHERE ville_latitude_deg BETWEEN 48.0462165495 AND 48.9471174505 
AND ville_longitude_deg BETWEEN -0.45045045045 AND 0.45045045045 
AND ville_population_2012 > 3000 Limit 1
```

Now this query is executed in 4 seconds ... 
**How Can I Optimize this ?** 
Thank you.

Comment: For start dont use * but declare only the 5 fields you want

Comment: have you index on the column involved  in on clause ?  and ville_population_2012?

Comment: can you please add the table structures as well (what columns are of which type).

Comment: I think a covering index on (lat,lon) would be optimal.

Comment: Indexing on village name could work, but for lat/long you need a spatial index

Comment: @Andomar, Just to clarify, what you say depends on column data type, right?

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla: No, it depends on the type of condition. A normal index can't resolve a range query (like "between") efficiently. For example, an index on `orderdate` won't help with `select * from sale_order where orderdate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-02'`

Comment: @apomene, there are some performance (memory or time) differences with use * instead of mention fields in Mysql?, because i usually hear that there are no differences in time perfomance.

Comment: @Andomar, i read that spatial index are include in SQL Server in version 2012, what was happening before that?, another reason of use spatial index is the data type (geometry or geography) like says in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265.aspx "A spatial index is a type of extended index that allows you to index a spatial column", or i am wrong, thank for help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hin that the lat/long should be evaluated first?  Maybe:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    inspitravel.villes_france_free 
        WHERE   ville_latitude_deg BETWEEN 48.0462165495 AND 48.9471174505 
                AND ville_longitude_deg BETWEEN -0.45045045045 AND 0.45045045045 
        ) villes
JOIN    inspitravel.villes_booking 
ON      villes.ville_nom_reel = villes_booking.full_name 
WHERE   ville_population_2012 > 3000
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: It returns empty results !

Comment: Your'e right, moving the `limit 1` to the inner query was incorrect!  Glad the index suggestion helped

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. 
First **I removed * by all my needed field names.** Thanks @apomene

```
SELECT villes_france_free.ville_nom_reel, villes_booking.full_name, villes_booking.number_of_hotels, villes_booking.deeplink  FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free 
INNER JOIN inspitravel.villes_booking ON villes_france_free.ville_nom_reel = villes_booking.full_name 
WHERE ville_latitude_deg BETWEEN 48.0462165495 AND 48.9471174505 
AND ville_longitude_deg BETWEEN -0.45045045045 AND 0.45045045045 
AND ville_population_2012 > 3000 Limit 1
```

**Then, Like you said, I had to Index columns involved in ON clause.**
 Thanks @scaisEdge
Now this query is executed in 0.100 sec ! Perfect.

Comment: You get one index per table, so you may as well add a covering index on (lat,lon)